# Random Tkinter window placement not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a Tkinter program, that when executed, places the window at a random point of the screen each time. For the x-axis, I use a range between 100 and 1280, and for the Y-axis I use a range between 100 and 800.

```
import tkinter
import random

randx = random.randint(100,1280)
randy = random.randint(100,800)

win = tkinter.Tk()
win.geometry("500x300+randx()+randy()")
win.title('button')

win.mainloop()
```

When executed, it gives me this error:
"_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "500x300+randx()+randy()"

I'm unsure how the placement system works. if I just plug in other single numbers instead of "randx()" or "randy()", it works, but then it's not random each time. what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `randx` and `randy` are not functions, so you don't need the parentheses after them.
To put `randx` and `randy` into the string, you need to use string formatting like below:

```
win.geometry("500x300+{}+{}".format(randx, randy))
```

To learn more about string formatting, have a look at [this](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).

Comment: using fstrings is even more concise: `win.geometry(f"500x300+{randx}+{randy}")`